# PayPal Express Checkout Shipping Calculations

Tags: paypal, checkout

I would like to:

- Have the user log into paypal
- Fetch the users information (billing&shipping addresses)
- Then calculate the shipping fee
- Place the payment

But, how can I receive the address and calculate the fee before I place the payment?

```
<script>
paypal.Button.render({
    // Configure environment
    env: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalEnv; ?>',
    client: {
        sandbox: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalClientID; ?>',
        production: '<?php echo $paypal->paypalClientID; ?>'
    },
    // Customize button (optional)
    locale: 'de_DE',
    style: {
        size: 'small',
        color: 'gold',
        shape: 'rect',
    },
    // Set up a payment
    payment: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.create({
            transactions: [{
                amount: {
                    total: '10',
                    currency: 'EUR'
                }
            }]
      });
    },
    // Execute the payment
    onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.payment.execute()
        .then(function () {
            window.location = "process.php?paymentID="+data.paymentID+"&token="+data.paymentToken+"&payerID="+data.payerID+"&pid=<?php echo $productID; ?>";
        });
    }
}, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

Instead of "return actions.payment.execute()" calling the execute directly, I would like to fetch the address, then show the final basket with all the costs and then click on "pay now" - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is an older version of PayPal's checkout.js

Start by switching to the latest version of the PayPal Checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

Demo of client-side pattern: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

In the onApprove function, you can use the `data` object to get the address and do Javascript calculations about adding shipping before the capture() call with a modified total.

If you want to do the calculations on your server rather than in Javascript (more secure/reliable), use a server-side pattern:

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Answer (score 0):

thank you! mhhh okay but what has to be in the serverside part? i dont see any example of the actions to receive the buyers adress information before checkout and afterwards. ?

/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create